# Get value of key within Map in Java

Tags: java, string, jsp, dictionary

I'm not at Java developer but I'm trying to figure out how to get a value from a Map. I'm using a basic (old) Struts app with no fancy stuff or JSTL afaik. I can get all the key/value pairs to output by converting the Map to a String:

```
<% String myValue = pageContext.getSession().getAttribute("myMap").toString(); %>
```

However, when I try to access a specific key it doesn't work:

```
<% String myValue = pageContext.getSession().getAttribute("myMap['myKey']").toString(); %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<% String myValue = ((Map) pageContext.getSession().getAttribute("myMap")).get("myKey").toString(); %>
resp.
<% String myValue = ((Map) session.getAttribute("myMap")).get("myKey").toString(); %>
// because session is an implicit object in JSP
```

However, I would strongly discourage you from using such spaghetti code in JSP. If you need to output the "myKey" value, you can use e.g. `<c:out>` tag with EL:

```
<c:out value="${session.myMap.myKey}" />
or
<c:out value="${session['myMap']['myKey']" />
```

Comment: Excellent! I'm actually doing a string replacement using `.replaceAll()` with the `myValue` string at the end so I assumed the wasn't a way to utilize a simple `<c:out ... />`

Comment: See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_function_replace.htm (actually, the whole JSP tutorial at Tutorials Point is worth at least a quick read).

Comment: With regards to the JSTL tutorials unfortunately I can't use the functions lib. Adding `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>` causes a "No tag library could be found" error with my codebase.

Comment: You probably need to install JSTL (https://jstl.java.net/, or https://tomcat.apache.org/taglibs/standard/ if you use Tomcat). You have to put the JAR file into the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming .getAttribute("myMap") will return the Map object itself, you could use:
`<% String val = pageContext.getSession().getAttribute("myMap").get(myKey).toString %>`

Comment: As mentioned in the comments above, you'll probably have to cast to Map like so:
<% String val = ((Map<KEY.class, VALUE.class>) pageContext.getSession().getAttribute("myMap")).get(myKey).toString(); %>

Answer (score 0):

Mostly the session will return the Object type. Please try the below one.

```
HashMap hmap11=(HashMap)pageContext.getSession().getAttribute("myMap");
```

it may work.